# Reversing a String Using Recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion, input, reverse

I am having a bit of a problem here. I am trying to reverse a user inputted string using recursion, but I keep getting an error. Basically, a parameterless void, recursive function should be called to print out the string backwards. I get an error on the 23rd line only under the reverse word, which states "The method reverse() in the type RecursionReversal is not applicable for the arguments (String)". There are quick fixes to it given in Eclipse, but none of them are what I need. Am I missing something?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecursionReversal
{
    public static String origChars;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter 5 characters:");
        origChars= input.nextLine();        

        reverse();
    }

    public static void reverse()
    {
        if(origChars.length() <= 1)
            return;
        else
            reverse(origChars.substring(1) + origChars.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know what that error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should take a `String` argument; using a `static` field might work but has a bad code smell. Anyway, take the last character in the input `String` and then substring everything else. Like,

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1)
        return str;
    else
        return Character.toString(str.charAt(str.length() - 1))
                + reverse(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
}
```

If you must do it with the global, it could be done with something similar but you must update `origChars` before you call `reverse()` (without arguments) like

```
private static String origChars;
public static void reverse() {
    if (origChars.length() <= 1)
        System.out.print(origChars);
    else {
        System.out.print(origChars.charAt(origChars.length() - 1));
        origChars = origChars.substring(0, origChars.length() - 1);
        reverse();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I had, then I realized that I need to use a parameterless void function.

Comment: @evarias Look at the my second version, notice the else requires updating `origChars`; and `reverse()` can't take arguments.

Comment: it works but I thought that for recursion, there needed to be an argument inside the reverse function?

Answer (score 2):

Add an argument to the `reverse` method to correspond to the method call being made within the method

```
public static void reverse(String input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining parameters or a return type for the reverse function. To use recursion I would recommend replacing your reverse method with

```
public static String reverse(String s)
{
    if(s.length() <= 1)
        return s;
    else
        reverse(s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0));
}
```

You have the right idea with the `reverse(s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0));` statement but you need a return type otherwise you have no way to get the result. Secondly, without a parameter, the method has no way to know what part of the `String` to reverse.

Lastly, to make it work, from your `main`, call `origichars = reverse(origChars);` instead of calling `reverse();`.

Comment: Yep I understand that part, but I was trying to find a way to do this with a parameterless void function.

Comment: I just added an answer that does with a parameterless void function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with a parameterless void function. `reverse()` takes off the first `char`, calls `reverse()` then puts the `char` back on the end of `origChars`.

```
public static void reverse()
{
    if(origChars.length() <= 1)
        return;
    char first = origChars.charAt(0);
    origChars = origChars.substring(1);
    reverse();
    origChars+=first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String reverseUsingRecursion(String str){
    if(str.length() == 0 || str.length() == 1){
        return str;
    }   
    String reverseString = reverseUsingRecursion(str.substring(1)) 
                           + str.charAt(0); 
    return reverseString;          
}
```